# Want fixed size image or drawable ( in inches ) on all devices

Tags: android, android-layout, cocos2d-x, dpi, cocos2d-x-3.0

I tried this doing with device dpi. Getting dpi and scaling image accordingly but does not work on all devices. I have written code in `cocos2dx framework` and tried it on android, devices like `xolo` and `xiomi` my note does not display the desired result (`image size different from rest devices`).
My concept is if one device has 320 dpi and another has 240 dpi than

**1 inch = 320 px(in 1st device) = 240 px(in 2nd device)**

for android I have used

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
metrics.xdpi 
metrics.ydpi
```

and scaled accordingly for each phone

1. Is it possible that all devices not return correct dpi.
2. Is this a correct way of doing it?
3. Is there an alternate solution for obtaining this result?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. yes. 3. a big hardcoded table of all known devices and their actual dpis.

Comment: where could i find list of actual dpis ?

Comment: If google can't find a pre-made list, you need to make this yourself by getting device specs and comparing physical screen size with advertised pixel dimensions for all the devices that you are principally targeting.

Answer (score 0):

For some devices `xdpi` and `ydpi` metrics are returning wrong numbers and you cannot rely on them. Since API 17 you can also use `getRealMetrics()`. It should give you accurate values for `xdpi` and `ydpi`.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(dm);

dm.xdpi
dm.ydpi
```

Comment: Its still not working. I think these values are feed by the manufacturers and through "adb shell dumpsys display" it shows wrong x and y dpi